# The Android Hello World app is zoomed in and blurry on my nexus 7

Tags: android, screen-size

I am starting android development and I am following the first training guide on developer.android.com.

I created an app like this:

```
android create project --target <target-id> --name MyFirstApp \
--path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --activity MainActivity \
--package com.example.myfirstapp
```

When I install it on my nexus 7 it's all zoomed in blurry.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to have the `supports-screens` set up in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.gpsinsight.gpsandroid"                                                             
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's blurry because the app was created for a phone-sized device originally, and when you run it on your tablet, the app is blown up to scale with the 7" screen.

Comment: Usually on tablets there is a button on the bottom right to allow you to either stretch- or zoom-to-fill. Select stretch-to-fill and it should remove the fuzziness.

Comment: I want to know what I can do in the source of my app to fix it.

Comment: If you specified the textview as `<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" />` and in the the java file all you did was override the onCreate method and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, then there is no reason it shouldn't be blurry.

Comment: @DrewLeSueur Glasses could also be a solution.

Comment: I think my real question might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085922/android-is-not-choosing-the-correct-layout-file