# Android is not choosing the correct layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have 3 different layout files

```
layout/
    main.xml
layout-large/
    main.xml
layout-sw600dp/
    main.xml
```

My nexus 7 is always using the `layout/main.xml`

Is there something I have to do to get it to use the `layout-sw600dp/main.xml` file?

Comment: You will have to change density and resolution by other programs. I think it is possible bt you could also use emulator device with that params. By the way, I've made simple app to tell your density and show what image is taken from resources. Please check this, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=m.mokrzycki.phoneifnormations I hope It will help you some :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs didn't mention it but you have to have the `supports-screens` set up right in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.gpsinsight.gpsandroid"                                                             
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```